# How many integers $q(m,n)=\sum_m^np_k=p_m\cdot p_n$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ denote the $n^{th}$ prime number; $p_1=2,p_2=3,p_3=5$, etc.

**Question:** Are the infinitely many pairs of integers $(m,n)$ for which $m\le n$ and
$$
\sum_{k=m}^n p_k=p_m\cdot p_n?
$$
For example, $(1,3)$, $(2,6)$, $(3,11)$ and $(4,16)$ are all valid pairs, since
$$10=\sum_{k=1}^3p_k=p_1\cdot p_3=2\cdot5$$
$$39=\sum_{k=2}^6p_k=p_2\cdot p_6=3\cdot13$$
$$155=\sum_{k=3}^{11}p_k=p_3\cdot p_{11}=5\cdot31$$
$$371=\sum_{k=4}^{16}p_k=p_4\cdot p_{16}=7\cdot53$$
Up to $m=1000$ no other valid pair exists.

Many thanks.

**Edit:** I used the following Python code:

```
from sympy import prime, nextprime
m = int(input('n: '))
for i in range(1, m+1):
    sum = pn = pm = prime(i)
    while sum < pm*pn:
        pn = nextprime(pn)
        sum += pn
        if sum == pm*pn:
            print(pm, pn, sum)
```

Comment: I haven't been working on it, but the inequality $$\frac16n\log n<p_n<12\left(n\log n+n\log\frac{12}e\right)$$ could help. (Source: Introduction to Analytic Theory by Tom M. Apostol, p. 82).

Comment: @ajotatxe Thanks a lot.

Comment: This looks very difficult. If we use the toy model $p_n=n\log n$, then
$$\sum_{k=n}^m p_k\approx\sum_k k\log k\approx \int_n^m x\log x\,dx$$
and the integral is
$$I=\bigg\vert_n^m\left(\frac12x^2\log x-\frac14x^2\right).$$
This reaches $p_np_m\approx nm \log n \log m$ when $m$ is in the ballpark of $2n\log n$. Meaning that the number of solutions might even be infinite.

Comment: Certain restrictions may help ... Start and end both 1 mod 6 primes, well then their product is 1 mod 6, and they need either 1 mod 6 difference in number of 1 and -1 mod 6 to appear, or a -1 mod 6 overage in favor of -1 mod 6.

Comment: (+1). Nevertheless, I would like to have an explanation how you can be sure that for $m\le 1\ 000$ (no matter what $n$ is) , there are no further solutions.